# Bonobo git server default user credentials

Tags: git, bonobo

I am hosting bonobo git server on my iis and I left the configuration options to their defaults, meaning that it is supposed to be using its internal membership service.  Whenever I navigate to my server, I am prompted with a Login screen before I have registered any users and no combination of actions that I have tried is leading me to a Member Registration page.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get bonobo's internal membership database populated?

The documentation seems to be non-existent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Upon further review**, I found the default credentials for the admin user mentioned innocuously within the middle of the Installation Instructions.
**{username:admin,password:admin}**

Personally, I feel they should be presented more prominently or be searchable in the documentation. 
At any rate, that's the answer.